# Exogenous Instrumental variable

Tags: statistics

[image]

For what's given, all I know is that U and V are correlated, but Z is independent of them. How are we supposed to find Z? For part b, is it just simply $Y_i=\beta_0+ \beta_1 (\pi_0+\pi_1 Z_i + V_i)+ U_i$?

And any help with part a? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Solved part b. Can someone help with part a?

Comment: Also anyone knows how to solve part c?